# SEO Friendly iFrames-- Non-blocking to parent page from downloading its elements

Tags: iframe, seo

I am planning to include iFrame in my wordpress site homepage for one reason-- improve homepage speed for SEO purposes. Correct me if I'm wrong, I found out that iframe blocks loading on parent page (old browsers perhaps). Now, here's the idea: I want to divide my homepage into two. The top would be the parent page's light elements and below would be an iframe showing recent posts with heavy elements. I want to load the parent's elements first before the iframe's. Also, prevent browser from showing busy indicator which I intend to use GIF image only on the iframe.

Summary:

Page with SEO friendly iframe.

Loads parent elements first w/o being blocked by iFrame

iframe loads after loading parent page's elements

Prevent showing browser's busy indicator while loading the iframe

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there's something like seo friendly iframes. Yes of course in last year google started indexing iframes but it's still worst than normal. (problems with links for iframe sites, google dont know how to index it, or with the same address or with other). It is better to have slow speed, than having iframes(and i am sure of that:) )

Comment: Okay, let's say that the SEO I'm refering is the page speed, not the crawlability (forgive the word) of the site. The content of that iframe would still be crawled by bots because it will be included in the sitemap. All I want is to show the main elements of the parent page so the visitors will not wait for the whole page to finish loading. I want a lightning fast homepage.

Comment: yes but even when you include it in sitemap it is not the best idea. it will not match content witch this links from iframe. So you will have two other sites not one, and one of them only with links(stupid content). Another thing is that you will not have any other links to content from homepage(vary bad for seo). If you need to do this do it with ajax. Frames are realy uncomfortable (display diffrent in other browsers). For that u need to do somewhere site only with this links. how to do it check in wordpress documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you use a sitemap the spiders will consider the origin page of the iframe as part of the website structure, provided the origin page is hosted in the same domain. Although, the page indexed appearing in a SERP will be the origin page, not the one holding the iframe. This could be confusing to the reader.